# How to use fanout exchange in rabbitmq-c?

Tags: c, exchange-server, rabbitmq

I am testing c client in rabbitmq in centos 5.5. If I want to use the fanout exchange to push messages to every queues,  how should set the parameter routingkey?

The function amqp_basic_publish is shown below:

```
 amqp_basic_publish(amqp_connection_state_t state,
                   amqp_channel_t channel,
                   amqp_bytes_t exchange,
                   amqp_bytes_t routing_key,
                   amqp_boolean_t mandatory,
                   amqp_boolean_t immediate,
                   amqp_basic_properties_t const *properties,
                   amqp_bytes_t body)
```

Is the parameter routing_key meaningless when using the fanout exchange? If so, what value should I set this parameter to?
Thanks for any useful suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The routing key does nothing and can be set to anything when you have a Fanout exchange.

Take a look [here](http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/03/28/rabbitmq-for-windows-exchange-types/) for a really good summary of the different exchange types.